# Is it safe to call .Close (.Dispose) on an EventWaitHandle directly after .Set?

Tags: c#, multithreading, waithandle, event-wait-handle

I have one thread waiting on an EventWaitHandle (AutoResetEvent):

```
AutoResetEvent.WaitOne();
```

I have another thread signalling the first thread to continue

```
AutoResetEvent.Set();
AutoResetEvent.Close();
```

Is it safe to call .Close direct after .Set, in other words will it be guaranteed that the waiting thread has continueed before the AutoResetEvent is disposed?

Comment: The [docs for `Close`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.waithandle.close(v=vs.110).aspx) say: _"Once this method is called, references to the current instance cause undefined behavior."_  Whether that's for new references to it, or existing ones such as your call to `WaitOne` isn't clarified.  But I wouldn't want to try it... why not close/dispose it from the one doing the waiting?

Comment: Because the waiting is optional, so it won't get disposed then if the waiting isn't done...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is safe if things work out exactly as described in your question. If you *know* that all threads were already waiting when you called set, those threads will have been signaled and everything will be fine since all threads that are waiting are guaranteed to be released before a call to set returns.

However, if you for some reason experience a race and call set and close *before* the thread has started to wait you will get a exception when trying to wait. So in practice you are better off avoiding this pattern. IMHO

Comment: I think you can never know that threads are waiting. They could be descheduled 1 instruction before entering the wait and other threads could not tell.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So I give up this pattern. I found a managed implementation for an AutoResetEvent, and I might try my luck with that one: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/244638/Managed-Thread-Synchronization

Comment: @usr Exactly, that's why I think this is a bad pattern to rely on. I don't know enough about the scenario here to recommend some other solution, but it could be possible to implement some simple thread safe countdown where the thread signaling and closing handle checks count before closing handle to make sure all consumers are done with their task. Or simply reverse dependencies..